# Why it is impossible to have a complex number with Integer number as real part and approximate number as imaginary part?

Tags: complex, number-representation

```
1/3 + 3. I
(*output 
0.333333+3.I*)
2 + 3. I
(*output
2.+3.I*)
```

According to the above code, it seems impossible to have a complex number with Integer or exact number as real part and approximate number as imaginary part. The exact number as real part is converted to approximate number automatically, and forcibly.

I look up it in the official doc and didn't find any explaination.

Can some one give a documentation reference explaining this mechanism?

---

Thanks for @Nasser's comment. I read your link and summaries as below:

1. Complex number is atomic in that its two constituent parts(`Re[]` and `Im[]`) can only be both exact number type(`Integer`,`Rational`) or both inexact number type(`Real`).
2. If either one part of a complex number is inexact, the other part is coerced to inexact number;
3. As a result,  `2.5I` is actually evaluated internally as `0. +2.5I`. Because the hidden exact 0 as real part of `2.5I` is coerced to inexact 0.0.

Does I get it right? 
I wonder where you guys learned these knowledge. I spend a lot of time search in the official documentation and found nothing say these traits of complex number.

Comment: This is because Complex number in Mathematica is atomic. Sorry but this looks like duplicate.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks, indeed, I edited the question;

Comment: `I wonder where you guys learned these knowledge. I spend a lot of time search in the official documentation and found nothing say these traits of complex number` it is there in the help section. But need to go over the examples to see it. May be it should have been made more clear and explicit, in the top level description instead of in the examples. I agree. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HmmrH.png)  here is the link https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complex.html

Comment: I once saw this `x = 1 + 2. I` example in documents, but the doc didn't say anything about why it happens and what its implications, so I come here...
Thanks again. @Nasser

Comment: "When any number in an arithmetic expression is given with an explicit decimal point, you get an approximate numerical result for the whole expression." [`ref`](tutorial/Numbers#9834) Complex numbers are no different from any other expression in Mathematica.

Comment: Good reference! @BobHanlon